# Lazy-add DataMapper results in a loop

Tags: sql, ruby, datamapper

When I want to do OR-queries with DataMapper I use

```
result = MyModel.all(:first_name.like => '%john%') + MyModel.all(:last_name.like => '%john%')
```

This works fine and generates only one SQL query.
How can I create the same result with properties given in an array?

```
result = [ :first_name, :last_name ].reduce([]) do |sum, prop|
  sum + MyModel.all(prop.like => '%john%')
end
```

Although this works, it uses two separate SQL queries which is not what I want. Is there a way to create such a "lazy" query in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The problem is that you cannot use an empty regular array (`[]`) as the initial value of the result variable. I did not want to dig into the DataMapper internals too deeply, so I just used additional checking for the first assignment of `result`, like this:

```
result = nil
[ :first_name, :last_name ].each do |prop|
  cur = MyModel.all(prop.like => '%john%')
  next unless cur
  result ? result.nil? cur : result + cur
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a WHERE clause by hand. Something like this:

```
props = []
values = []
[ :first_name, :last_name ].each do |prop|
  props << "(#{prop} LIKE ?)"
  values << '%john%'
end
MyModel.all :conditions => [props.join(' OR ')] + values
```

Comment: Sure this works, but I think it is a very unelegant solution, especially since there is a better way to do it.